# If $\int_\Omega f\phi=0$ then $f=0$ a.e. in $\Omega$

Tags: real-analysis

> 1. If $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ satisfies that $\int_\Omega f\phi=0$ for all $\phi\in\mathcal C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ then $f=0$ a.e. in $\Omega$.
> 2. If $f\in\mathcal C^0(\Omega)$ satisfies that $\int_\Omega f\phi=0$ for all $\phi\in\mathcal C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ then $f\equiv 0$ in $\Omega$.

I'm a little stuck, what I've done for 1. is, we know that $0\le\int_\Omega |f-\phi|^2$, then we start to operate:
$$0\le\int_\Omega |f-\phi|^2=\int_\Omega(f-\phi)^2=\int_\Omega f^2-2f\phi+\phi^2=\int_\Omega f^2 -(2\int_\Omega f\phi)+\int_\Omega \phi^2=(\star)$$

but since $\int_\Omega f\phi=0$, then:

$$(\star)=\int_\Omega f^2+\int_\Omega \phi^2,\Rightarrow \int_\Omega |f-\phi|^2=\int_\Omega f^2+\int_\Omega \phi^2$$

and because $0\le\int_\Omega f^2,\int_\Omega \phi^2=\int_\Omega |\phi|^2$ then $\int_\Omega |\phi|^2\le\int_\Omega |f-\phi|^2$ hence $\|\phi\|_2\le\|f-\phi\|_2$.

On the other hand, we know that $\mathcal C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$, then $\|f-\phi\|_2<\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon>0$, $\Rightarrow \|\phi\|_2<\varepsilon$ ... and that's it, but maybe, is it more useful to consider $\|f\|_2\le\|f-\phi\|_2$? That way $\|f\|_2<\varepsilon\Rightarrow f(x)=0$ almost for every $x\in\Omega$.

But I've got nothing else from there.

Now, for 2. do we get it from 1.?

Comment: For (2), you need the fact that if a continuous function is $0$ a.e., then it is zero. (prove this!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways to proceed:

Way (1): Given the inequality $\|\phi\|_2 \le \|f - \phi\|_2$ for all $\phi$, apply it to an approximating sequence

$$\phi_n \to f \text{ in } L^2(\Omega)$$

Then

$$\|\phi_n\|_2 \le \|f - \phi_n\|_2 \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$, so $\phi_n \to 0$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. Now you're done.

---

Way (2): Given $g \in L^2(\Omega)$, approximate it in the $L^2(\Omega)$ norm by a sequence $g_n$ of smooth functions; then by the assumption of (i),

$$\int_{\Omega} f g_n = 0$$

for every $n$. On the other hand, try showing that $$\int_{\Omega} f g_n \to \int_{\Omega} fg$$

in which case you're done. To do this, you might find it useful to instead study

$$\int_{\Omega} f (g_n - g)$$

and apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Now the only function that's $L^2$-orthogonal to everything is the zero function (prove this!).

---

To prove (ii), show that such an $f$ must be zero on $L^2(B_n)$, where $B_n$ is the ball of radius $n$; to this end, consider the restriction of the function to that ball.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing two ways to do it. I'm pretty much done with (i) using way2. Now, for (ii) I think it's easier to prove it by contradiction, that way, since $f$ is continuous there's a $B_n(x_0,\delta)$ with $\delta>0$ and $f(x_o)\not=0$, where the function is not $0$, I don't know... can I say from here that because of (i) $f|_{B_n(x_0,\delta)}=0$ a.e. in $B_n(x_0,\delta)$?

Comment: oh... but I don't know if $f$ is in $L^2(B_n)$, what if I get an infinite integral? Can we take $\bar {B}_n(x_0,\delta)$, instead of the open ball? so $f$ could be in $C^0_c$.

Comment: @AnaGalois You'll have to use the fact that the (closed) ball of any radius is compact; a continuous function is necessarily (essentially) bounded on all compact sets, so we have the estimate $$\|f\|_{L^2(B_n)}^2 \le \|f\|_{L^{\infty}(B_n)}^2 |B_n| < \infty$$